# Error with python decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I get this error

```
object has no attribute 'im_func'
```

with this

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f

    def __call__( self, *args ):
        return self.func(*args)
```

pylons code:

```
class TestController(BaseController):

    @Test
    def index(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

full error:

```
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/WebError-0.10.2-py2.5.egg/weberror/evalexception.py', line 431 in respond
  app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/repoze.who-1.0.18-py2.5.egg/repoze/who/middleware.py', line 107 in __call__
  app_iter = app(environ, wrapper.wrap_start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.3-py2.5.egg/beaker/middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.3-py2.5.egg/beaker/middleware.py', line 152 in __call__
  return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Routes-1.10.3-py2.5.egg/routes/middleware.py', line 130 in __call__
  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.5.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 125 in __call__
  response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.5.egg/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 324 in dispatch
  return controller(environ, start_response)
File '/project/lib/base.py', line 18 in __call__
  return WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.5.egg/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 221 in __call__
  response = self._dispatch_call()
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.5.egg/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 172 in _dispatch_call
  response = self._inspect_call(func)
File '/env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pylons-0.9.7-py2.5.egg/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 80 in _inspect_call
  argspec = cached_argspecs[func.im_func]
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'im_func'
```

Comment: Is that the code that generates the error? I see no sign of decorators, nor does it give me an error. `im_func` is an attribute of user defined methods (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-824).

Comment: its in pylons, does it matter? its on a method on a controller

Comment: Please provide the entire error traceback and the relevant code: i.e., In the error there should be a line number refering to which line caused the error, please provide that code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TestController.index` ends up an instance of `Test`, with no access to the `TestController` object. Also, only user defined methods (which must be functions, not objects) have an `im_func` attribute. You'll need to instantiate `Test` and have its `__call__` method return a function so that it can be passed the `TestController` instance.

```
class Test(object):
    def __call__( self, f):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # anything in the old Test.__call__ goes here.
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

class TestController(BaseController):
    @Test()
    def index(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

#### What's happening

A decorator:

```
@decorator
def foo(...):
```

is equivalent to:

```
def foo(...):
    ...
foo = decorator(foo)
```

In your original code,

```
    @Test
    def index(self):
```

creates an instance of `Test` and passes `index` to the constructor. The resulting object is assigned to the `index` property of `TestController`.

```
class TestController(BaseController)
    def index(self):
        ...
    index = Test(index)
```

`Test.__call__` doesn't get invoked until you try to call `TestController.index`. With `tc` an instance of `TestController`, `tc.index()` is equivalent to `tc.index.__call__()` or `Test.__call__(tc.index)`.

The problem is that within the call to `Test.__call__`, we've lost the reference to `tc`. It didn't exist when `Test.index` was defined, so there's no way of saving it. Moreover, it looks like Pylons performs some magic on the methods and it expects `tc.index` to be a user defined method (which has an `im_func` property), not an object (which doesn`t).

The approach I show you changes when `Test.__call__` is invoked and the type of `TestController.index`.

```
class Test(object):
    def __call__( self, f):
        # if done properly, __call__ will get invoked when the decorated method 
        # is defined, not when it's invoked
        print 'Test.__call__'
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # wrapper will get invoked instead of the decorated method
            print 'wrapper in Test.__call__'
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

The definition of `TestController.index` is equivalent to:

```
class TestController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        ...
    index = Test()(index) # note: Test.__call__ is invoked here.
    # 'index' is now 'wrapper' from Test.__call__

tc = TestController
tc.index() # wrapper from Test.__call__ is invoked here
```

Because `TestController.index` is a function rather than an object, `tc.index()` is equivalent to `TestController.index(tc)`, and we don't lose the reference to `tc`.

Comment: thanks, this fixes the error, but how does it work?  im a python beginner

Answer (score 1):

See http://pylonshq.com/project/pylonshq/ticket/589 ?

Is there any monkeypatching or other weirdness going on when you call it?
Full traceback and source for the caller would really help here.

Comment: using the standard pylons template

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this does not work as you expect, you have to understand how methods work in Python. When an attribute is looked up, its `__get__` method is called (if it exists) and what that returns is used instead of the attribute itself. The main use for this is implementing methods, special sorts of methods (like classmethods), properties and the like. There are similarly hooks for setting and deleting attributes, and it's all explained on http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/

Functions already have `__get__` magic built in, so they work as methods automatically, making a bound method passing the current instance when they are looked up. A class you defines does not automatically have this, so you have to define it manually, as such:

```
from functools import partial
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.func(*args)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is not None:
            # Then the method was called on an instance, not the class itself
            return partial(self, obj)
            # Some people might find it easier to phrase this 
            # partial(self.func, obj) in this case, which would be equivalent. I 
            # prefer doing partial(self, obj) since then I can place all the 
            # logic for calling in one place.
        else:
            # The method was called on the class, not a particular instance, 
            # so we're not going to do anything special. Functions return 
            # unbound methods (which typecheck their first arguments) in this 
            # case, which I've always thought was an iffy approach.
            return self

class Foo(object):
    @Test
    def bar(self):
        return "hello world"

f = Foo()
print f.bar()
```

As far as the *actual* error you are getting, I'm not 100% sure why you do. I wonder if it is not Pylons weirdness I don't know about. The entirety of the relevant file(s) and the full traceback can go a long way to helping people diagnose problems.